# Processes in Sequence design pattern

Tags: java, c#, oop, design-patterns

**Scenario:**
I have some methods that process some steps of a kind of workflow process. Each method do something in a object and pass on the same object to another method. Something like that:

```
void MethodA(SomeType obj)
{
    // Some Process

    MethodB(obj);
}

void MethodB(SomeType obj)
{
    // Some Process

    MethodC(obj);
}

void MethodC(SomeType obj)
{
    // keep going...
}
```

**Complication:**
The system is growing and I notice that I need to call this 'queue of steps' in some different places of the system. But to other places a few steps change, some can't be executed and new ones need to be executed. In general the queue changes but the steps don't.

**Question**
Is there a Design Pattern that allow me to build steps separated and join them only when I need to run?

Comment: Instead of having the methods call the next one, have a wrapper method with a logical name call them in sequence instead. Basically decouple the work from the sequence. For example, `void DoSomeSequence(SomeType obj) { MethodA(obj); MethodB(obj); MethodC(obj); } void DoSomeOtherSequence(SomeType obj) { MethodA(obj); MethodC(obj); MethodZ(obj); }` Would something like this work out?

Comment: You might want to look at the command pattern. It's real use comes with sequencing multiple commands. A lot like the other examples/answers already.

Comment: Do you reuse queues?

Comment: Why did you tag both Java and C#?

Comment: Because, they are both oop, both descending of C, and this is not really a question about code, just about oop and design patterns. So fit properly to both. And my code snippet can be compiled to both languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the *Builder* pattern:

```
public class MyObject {

    public static class MyObjectBuilder {
        private MyObject obj;
        public MyObjectBuilder() {
            obj = new MyObject();
        }

        public MyObjectBuilder methodA() {
            // edit something with obj
            return this;
        }

        public MyObjectBuilder methodB() {
            // edit something with obj
            return this;
        }

        public MyObjectBuilder methodC() {
            // edit something with obj
            return this;
        }

        public MyObject build() {
            return obj;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyObject a = new MyObjectBuilder()
                .methodA()
                .methodB()
                .methodC().build();
        MyObject b = new MyObjectBuilder()
                .methodA()
                .methodA()
                .methodB()
                .methodB().build();
        MyObject c = new MyObjectBuilder()
                .methodC()
                .methodB()
                .methodA()
                .methodC()
                .methodB().build();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is interesting, it's the same of jQuery right? +1.

Comment: @JonnyPiazzi Kind of--jQuery doesn't have builders as far as I know, but it does use the fluent interface pattern a lot. The two things are very similar.

Comment: Yes you're right, now that you say makes all sense, stupid thought of me. Tnks.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about design pattern but you can achieve this as below:

```
void Method(SomeType obj)
{
    MethodA(obj);
    MethodB(obj);
    MethodC(obj);
}

void MethodA(SomeType obj)
{
}

void MethodB(SomeType obj)
{
}

void MethodC(SomeType obj)
{
}
```

In this way you can rearrange these methods anytime anywhere you want.

Comment: Normally [template method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) design pattern includes `virutal`/`abstract` for `MethodX` methods... Otherwise pretty reasonable.

Comment: After thinking hard about the other answers, I notice that bring a design pattern to this problem will turn my code more complex that without one. So I decide to go with your solution.